# My Text and View stylesheet styles is not able to render however Box screen text content is showing anything I missed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

My `Text` and `View` stylesheet styles is not able to render however Box screen text content is showing. Anything I missed?

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View} from "react-native";

const BoxScreen = () => {
    return( 
    <View styles = {styles.viewStyle}>
        <Text styles = {styles.textStyle}>Boxs screen</Text>
    </View>
    ); 
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    viewStyle: {
        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: 'black'
    },
    textStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'red',
        marginVertical: 20
    }
});
export default BoxScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding prop styles instead of `style` prop, just rename the styles to `style`, below is a working code.

```
const BoxScreen = () => {
return( 
  <View style = {styles.viewStyle}>
     <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>Boxs screen</Text>
  </View>
);
};
```

Here is an example of your styles with your code.
[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/Ol8j-l12o)